# Looping through groups with deldir() in R

Tags: r, deldir

I have inputted some data consisting of three columns, X,Y and Group.

I am looking to get the underling data for a voronoi diagram for each group.

By using

```
a=deldir(Test.data$X,Test.data$Y,rw=c(0,1,0,1))
```

I succesfully create the voronoi data for the entire dataset. However I do not know how to iterate this process through the different groups that I have in the dataset.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have expereince with the ggplot function and know in here I can simply add a third dimension, something like

```
ggplot(Test.data,aes(x=X,y=Y,colour=Group))
```

Is there a way I can get a similar affect with the deldir() function

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a list of groups and then filter dataset. Below `lapply()` creates a list of deldir objects, one for each distinct group:

```
groups <- unique(Test.data$groupcol)

deldirList <- lapply(groups, function(g) {
                       temp <- Test.data[Test.data$groupcol==g,]
                       deldir(temp$X, temp$Y, rw=c(0,1,0,1))
               })
```

Comment: Hi Parfait, this output works perfectly, however I am now having issues writing the data to a csv, where I wasn't previously.

The deldirList writes as a 'LargeList' where as when i'm only working with small data sets it just saves as a 'List'.

In order to write the List to a CSV i am just using the function

write.csv(deldirList$delshs,"Output.csv")

This works with a normal list, but when using a large list, the output is just blank. Is there a different way to write large lists to csvs?

Comment: As mentioned, `deldirList` is a list of individual `deldir` objects. So this is a nested list. You can save individual items to file by adding `write.csv()` inside the `lapply()` loop or you can run `deldirAll <- do.call(rbind, deldirList); write.csv(deldirAll, "Output.csv")` to append all lists together.

Comment: How did it go? I do not have the package to test fully? Try a `dput(deldirList)` in you post to test other solutions.